# Sketch the graph of the polynomial function: $S(x) = \frac{1}{2} (x-1)^3 +4.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

[image]

The question is:

Sketch the graph of the the function by transforming the graph of an appropriate function of the form $y = x^n$. Indicate all x and y intercepts on the graph.

I am really trying to understand how to do this freehand before my test on Tuesday. Is there anything else that I should do to make this answer correct? Also, how do I show that the graph shrinks?

Should I make a t-table or is that a waste of time?

Comment: Your $x$ intercept is wrong. Your function looks like $y=x^3$; so it starts at $-\infty$ and goes to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the graph of $y=f(x)=x^{3}$.

[image]

Then draw $g(x)=(x-1)^{3}=f(x-1)$. This graph can be obtained by translating the graph of $f(x)$ to the right by +1 (Why?). Then draw $h(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^{3}=\frac{1}{2}g(x)$. Note that the values of $h(x)$ are reduced by a factor of $1/2$ with respect to the equivalent ones of $g(x)$.

Finally draw the graph of $S(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^{3}+4=\frac{1}{2}g(x)+4=h(x)+4.$

The $x$ intercept is the value of $x$ such that $S(x)=0$, i.e 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^{3}+4 &=&0\Leftrightarrow (x-1)^{3}+8=0\Leftrightarrow
(x-1)^{3}=-8 \\
&\Leftrightarrow &x-1=\sqrt[3]{-8}=-2\Leftrightarrow x=-2+1=-1
\end{eqnarray*}

The $y$ intercept is $S(0)=\frac{1}{2}(0-1)^{3}+4=\frac{7}{2}$.

ADDED. The two graphs are represented below: $f(x)=x^3$ (black) and $S(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^3+4$ (red)

[image]

Comment: How did you get the 8? I added 1/2 and 4 and got 9/2.

Comment: If you multiply the equation $\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^{3}+4 =0$ by $2$ you get the equivalent equation $(x-1)^{3}+8=0$.

Comment: Can you show me step by step how that it is done, since it look as if you did not distribute the 2 over the (x-1)^3? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Prologue  $$\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^{3}+4=0$$

$$2\left( \frac{1}{2}(x-1)^{3}+4\right) =2\left( 0\right) $$

$$2\left( \frac{1}{2}(x-1)^{3}\right) +2(4)=0$$

$$2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)(x-1)^{3}+8=0$$

$$1(x-1)^{3}+8=0$$

$$(x-1)^{3}+8=0$$

Comment: I still do not see why the (x-1)^3 has not been multiplied by 2. Is it because it is considered a factor of 1/2? Thus, they are one number?

Comment: @Prologue  By the associative property of multiplication $2(ab)=(2a)b$. In your case $a=1/2,b=(x-1)^3$. Is it clear now?

Comment: However, the associate property states that when you multiply three numbers, it does not matter which two you multiply first. You still have not multiplied the 2 into the (x-1)^3.

Comment: @Prologue Because I multiplied the 2 into the $1/2$. I cannot multiply both factors, the $1/2$ and the $(x-1)^3$ at the same time.

Comment: Because they (as in 1/2 and (x-1)^3) are considered a product? Similar to 8, (4)(2)?

Comment: @Prologue Yes, $(1/2)(x-1)^3$ is a product!

Comment: @Prologue You are welcome! Is it everything clear now?

Comment: Yes! One last question. This would apply for square roots that have values that come up out of them. For example; 2, square root of 2?

Comment: @Prologue The number under the square root sign should be non-negative. For instance $\sqrt{4}=2$, but $\sqrt{-4}$ is not defined (in the set of real numbers).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Maybe if you have the time, you could answer the newest question I posted on the forum seeing that you are a mathematician? Nonetheless, good day.